# How to drive a strip of 12 V no-addressable LEDs?

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I recently bought [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1M-5M-30-60-144-LED-WS2812B-5050-RGB-LED-Strip-Light-Addressable-FS-/322040909995?var=&hash=item4afb2250ab:m:mkeWFwy2GkxLZNpd-1JGBKA) LED Strip. I got the 5M 3528 300LEDs SMD RGB Non-waterproof ones. However, I am not sure how to use them. On the strip there is four wires. I have tried supplying power to the wire that says it needs power and then I put ground to each of the other wires, but that only turns on a colour. How do I make it so I can choose what colour to use (Wiring, Code, etc.)?

Comment: The page you link to sells different models of LED strips. Some of them, which are based on the WS2812B chip, allow the LEDs to be individually addressed. However, **the strip you got has no WS2812B** and is not addressable. The original title of your question, “_WS2812B LED Strip_”, was then extremely misleading. That's why @Orotavia posted a first answer that is not applicable to your strip. I edited the title to better reflect the reality.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I misunderstood! I assumed your LEDs were the 4pin serial version, whereas it makes more sense to me that they are the 6pin analog version. I must've brushed over the part where you said you grounded the colored wires and got that corresponding color.

You will provide 12V to the Power wire. To light the strip Red, you'd ground the Red wire, ground Blue for Blue, etc. Ground Red and Blue to light Purple, mixing colors etc etc.

So what if you wanted teal? or maybe a different shade of green? You'll need a way to generate PWM on the R, G, and B pins. Basically if you have an 80% duty cycle on Blue, that means it's only grounded 80% of the time. This corresponds to 80% brightness of the blue LEDs, then you could mix that with say 60% red and 10% green, or whatever you wanted to get a full 16 million colors. This is most easily accomplished with a microcontroller, and so I'll provide schematic and code tips for the simplest solution: an Arduino.

### Schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmTpO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I chose Pins 9, 10, and 11 of the Arduino because they are all PWM; you can choose any PWM pins you want (denoted by ~ or # usually). Just reflect those changes in the sketch.

Arduino pins are also only capable of sinking about 40mA if I remember correctly, so you'll need to control some MOSFETs with the PWM. I find you can't go wrong with the IRFZ44N, but that's just what I've had available to me.

### Arduino Sketch

How you control it is up to you; sensors, potentiometers, networked, bluetooth, constant fade pattern, there's a slew of options. So this code will tell you the necessary functions, but from there it's a matter of programming and integration of whatever else you want.

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  //255 -> 100%   ;   0 -> 0%
  analogWrite(9, 255); // turn red to 100%
  analogWrite(10, 0); // turn green to 0%
  analogWrite(11, 128); // turn blue to 50%
}
```

If this doesn't work, please let me know and I'll fix it. I forget if analogWrite is okay with being called in a simple, unrestrained loop over and over, and I also forget if Arduino pins have internal pull-downs

Comment: The line's on the strip are Power, Red, Green, Blue

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood! I've edited my post to hopefully better answer your question.

Comment: Note that the specs of the strip mention “_Working Input Voltage: 12VDC_”.

Comment: Note also that 1) The MOSFETs will invert your signal: Arduino pin HIGH → MOSFET conducting → strip line grounded → LED shines. 2) You may want to add pulldowns to the MOSFET gates, as the Arduino Uno has no internal ones: at power-up the output pins will float for about one second while the bootloader runs.

Comment: Oops, yeah I didn't even select the correct LED strip for 12V. I've also fixed the inversion issue and added pull-downs. Sorry for so many errors, Amorris, I think Edgar Bonet has caught them all now though, should be good to go.

Comment: This code only displays a bright red and a dim blue, not a teal colour or whatever colour you said it would make. If you could, please link to a page for some addressable WS2812B strips? Luckily, I only bought those for $4 :P

Comment: The PWM explanation section was just to describe PWM, sorry if that wasn't clear but it doesn't match up to the code. Modify the numbers as you see fit to get the color you want, be it teal or any other. As for an LED strip, just google 'WS2812B LED Strip', you'll find tons. WS2812B are the addressable ones, WS2812 (no B) are NOT addressable. Be careful with eBay sellers claiming they have addressable LEDs when they really don't. An alternative is SK6812 too, those are addressable.